# MongoDB Atlas What is the latency in ms?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mongodb-atlas, latency

I'm considering using MongoDB Atlas with GCP, is the Latency of this published?
If it is publicly available, I would like to know.

Best regard!!

I looked at the official website and Whitepaper.